# How to return proper arrays into a method and correctly fix the main method

Tags: java

I have an assignment that is supposed to prompt a user with a message box with 5 options: 1-add employee info(employee name, title, and salary) 2-edit the employee info 3-calculate salary 4-print all employees, titles, salaries 5-exit the program. I have the program running fine but when the user inputs the employee's name, title and salary..it does not save it into the array. Can you guys please help me and see what is the case? Thanks again.

```
public class Track_Employee_Information {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] EMPLOYEES = new String [15];
        String[] TITLE = new String [15];
        double[] SALARY = new double[15];
        int total_emp = 0;
        double total_salary = 0;
        int user_input;
        //Main includes user's responses to accept the right input.
        do {
             user_input = getUserInput(total_emp);
            if (user_input == 1) {
                getNewEmp(EMPLOYEES, TITLE, SALARY, total_emp);
            }
            if (user_input == 2) {
                getChangeEmp(user_input, EMPLOYEES, TITLE, SALARY);
            }
            if (user_input == 3) {
                getSalaryCost(total_emp, total_salary, SALARY);
            }
            if (user_input == 4) {
                getPrintEmployees(total_emp, EMPLOYEES, TITLE, SALARY);
            }
        } while (user_input != 5);

        if (user_input == 5) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static void getPrintEmployees(int total_emp, String[] EMPLOYEES, String[] TITLE, double[] SALARY) {
        //Display employees, titles, and salaries. If there are no employees, return error message.
        if (total_emp == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no employees or information to display");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, EMPLOYEES + "\n" + TITLE + "\n" + SALARY);
        }
    }

    private static double getSalaryCost(int total_emp, double total_salary, double[] SALARY) {
        //Calculate total salary costs and display. If there are no employees, return error message.
        if (total_emp == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no employees to calculate the salary from"); 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SALARY.length; i++) {
            total_salary += SALARY[i];
        }
        return total_salary;
    }

    private static void getChangeEmp(int user_input, String[] EMPLOYEES, String[] TITLE, double[] SALARY) {
        //Allow user to input name of pre-existing employee in order to change name, title, and salary. If employee does not exist, return error message.
        String askUserPrevEmp;

        askUserPrevEmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the pre-existing employee name");

        for (int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.length; i++) {
            try {
                while (askUserPrevEmp != EMPLOYEES[i]) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Employee does not exist.");
                    askUserPrevEmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the pre-existing employee name");
                }
                if (askUserPrevEmp.equals(EMPLOYEES[i])) {
                    EMPLOYEES[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the new Employee Name");
                    TITLE[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the new Employee title");
                    SALARY[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the new Employee salary"));
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a number not a character");
                }
                while ((SALARY[i] < 10000) || (SALARY[i] > 500000)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a NUMERIC value between $10,000 - $500,000");
                        SALARY[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the new Employee salary"));
                        }
                break;
            }
        }

    private static int getNewEmp(String[] EMPLOYEES, String[] TITLE, double[] SALARY, int total_emp) {
        //Allow user to enter new employee, title, salary. It will be validated as a numeric number and between $10,000-$50,000
        String emp_name = "";
        String emp_title = "";
        double emp_salary= 0;

        try {

        emp_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the employee name:");
        for (int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.length; i++) {
        EMPLOYEES[i] = emp_name;
        }

        emp_title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the employee title");
        for (int j = 0; j < TITLE.length; j++) {
        TITLE[j] = emp_title;
        }

        emp_salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the employee salary"));
        for (int k = 0; k < SALARY.length; k++) {
        while ((emp_salary < 10000) || (emp_salary > 500000)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a numeric value between $10,000 - $500,000");
                emp_salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the employee salary"));
                }
            SALARY[k] = emp_salary;
        }
            total_emp++;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a number not a character");
            emp_salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the employee salary"));
        }
        return total_emp;
    }

    private static int getUserInput(int total_emp) {
        //Presenting the user with a menu to select options. If there are more than 15 employees, return error message. If not then accept response.
        String askUserInput;
        int user_input = 0;
        askUserInput = "1) Add a new employee \n2) Change an employee \n3) Calculate salary costs \n4) Print employees \n5) Exit the program";

        user_input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, askUserInput));
        if ((user_input == 1) && (total_emp > 15)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have already reached the maximum number of 15 employees");
        }

        while ((user_input<1) || (user_input>5)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a number between 1-5");
            user_input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(askUserInput));
        }
        return user_input;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wall of text.

The values are being stored in the arrays in your getNewEmp method. The problem is that the value of total_emp never changes and as such, your system will complain that there are no employees to show.

You seem to be returning it after incrementing it in that method so you could probably fix it by changing the call to this:

```
total_emp = getNewEmp(EMPLOYEES, TITLE, SALARY, total_emp);
```

The loops you have in that method are also overwriting the contents of your arrays every time your getNewEmp function is invoked. You only need to write out the data to the appropriate index in the array, like so.

```
EMPLOYEES[total_emp] = emp_name;
TITLE[total_emp] = emp_title;
SALARY[total_emp] = emp_salary;
```

Also, getPrintEmployees will not work the way you're expecting it to. EMPLOYEES, TITLE, and SALARY are arrays and trying to print them by chucking them into a print statement will just give you a memory address or something. You need to loop through each individual entry:

```
String details = "";
for (int i = 0; i < total_emp; i++)
{
    details += EMPLOYEES[i] + "\n" + TITLE[i] + "\n" + SALARY[i] + "\n\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values aree being added but in the wrong way, dont use a loop or it will fill the entire array with the values from the inputs, which is what its doing. use an ArrayList and just do .add(emp_name), .add(emp_title), and so on. Using a loop to add the values will over write all the values with the current values being input by the user.

you also do not need to pass the arrays or any variables at all into any of the methods. taht might be whats going on, but i'm not totally sure i'll look at it some more.

Comment: The values are being stored, probably incorrectly, but still stored. The problem is with the total employee count not changing.